# Cannot download push-server dependency from icefaces or ibiblio repos

Tags: maven-2, maven, icefaces, pom.xml

the dependency push-server exists in both icefaces and ibiblio repos

http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/maven2/releases/org/icefaces/push-server/
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/icefaces/push-server/

both repos are added in my pom file

following this reference:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.icefaces/push-server/1.8.2

i added th dependency in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>push-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but when trying to install the application with maven 2, i am always getting build fail, and missing dependency on this artifact, but yet i can download other artifacts easily from here:

http://anonsvn.icefaces.org/repo/maven2/releases/org/icefaces/

so what's the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the type, You are trying to download war and if you don't specify type it defaults to jar, Just add the type it should solve your problem

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.icefaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>push-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.1</version>
  <type>war</type>
 </dependency>
```